# Contact Form 7 checkbox image not show up

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to know is there any possible to make Contact Form 7 do something like this?

[image]

Which I would like to let people choose the image using the checkbox. But what I can do is the contact form 7 only showing the images URL rather than the image. How can I fix it?

```
[checkbox your-country "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" "option 1" "option 2"]
```